# R.java not being generated for my android application

Tags: android

I just created a new Andriod project and it has error:

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

and I checked there is not file generated in gen folder.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Comment: In your project properties, select a different Android version to build against.This has solved my R.java generating problems 99% of the times.

Comment: check if any xml error are there or not

Comment: What are all the answers? Sum up everything you have tried

Comment: Cleaning the project doesn't help. Also there is no error in the XML file.

Comment: 1. I removed the andriod.R import statement.
2. Commented the lines containing the errors and cleaned the project.

Did not help !!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project>>Build All
if that doesn't work then try
Project>>Build Project
Be sure that you have removed tick from Build Automatically before doing this

EDIT
you can check out for invalid names in your res folder,check for errors in res/folder like:-

Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

all these names should be in lowercase, underscore and numbers between 0-9